# CLLocationCoordinate2DMake Type specifier missing

Tags: cllocationcoordinate2d

i have a problem and i don't have a clue how to solve it.

my code looks like this

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord[12]; 
coord[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5041,13.351);
```

It says:

> Type specifier  missing, defaults to 'int'

i don't get why. I tried different thinks and even saw similar code on this page, when i was looking for a hint.

Gz Adrian

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees latitude, CLLocationDegrees longitude)
```

And

```
typedef double CLLocationDegrees;
```

When you write `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(52.5041,13.351);` `52.5041` and `13.351` are maybe not considered as double.

Try like this:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *lat = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"52.5041"];
NSNumber *lng = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"13.351"];
coord[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat,lng);
```

Comment: and this for 12 diffrenet coordinates. isn't there a nicer method for this?

Comment: To make an iteration for your 12 different coordinates and the variables would be the `String` which will become `double`.

Comment: i feel so dumb...
it didn't work cause i tried it in my header file.
now put it in the locationManager and it works (the second line)